# How to tune PID (KP, KI, KD) for an actuator attached to a butterfly valve

Tags: pid-controller, automation

I'm currently tuning an actuator that was unstable. The person before me set the values to: KP = 0.04, KI = 0.07 and KD = 0. The system would oscillate between 90% open and 10% open and never reach steady state. The sensor is an air mass flow sensor relatively slow system.

The system is to maintain a steady SCFM of air at 700 with a dead band of 50 SCFM. Currently I got it to stop oscillating and reach a steady state but it takes about 7 minutes. Any recommendations on how to tune this?

Comment: "Slow" is death to PID. Most especially "unpredictably slow." The usual answer is to work hard, first, to improve that situation. Not tinker around with PID parameters. There's no use trying to put lipstick on a pig, so to speak. That said, are you able to arrange things so that you can go from completely closed to completely open (or some useful value, anyway) and then monitor the sensor response to that? Make a curve that includes any dead time, etc?

Comment: What happens if you include some derivative?

Comment: What's the open-loop response time of the system? And the sensor?